# Define action listener in custom button class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using javafx to create a GUI for my program, and have created a custom button `ComponentButton`. This extends `javafx.scene.control.Button`, the only real difference so far is that the button has an additional member variable. I would like all instances of my button to have an action listener attached to them, the listener would make use of the member variable. As a result I'd like to be able to define the action listener within the class definition of the button. As of yet I've been unable to make this work, I can make an action listener for each instance of the button but as there will be a lot of them I would rather avoid it.

Any ideas or alternative approaches are much appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit: Answered it**

I decided to make the view (where the button was used) implement `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. This meant that I could then add the method

```
@Override
public void handle(final ActionEvent event)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

This then meant that I could call `button.setOnAction(this);` to execute the action

Comment: "I can make an action listener for each instance of the button but as there will be a lot of them I would rather avoid it". Why would you want to avoid it? And "As of yet I've been unable to make this work" is not a statement of a problem. What actually goes wrong?

Comment: Surely `this.setOnAction(this);`, not `button.setOnAction(this);`?

Comment: I used it in the UI class, with a loop creating the buttons as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make the view (where the button was used) implement `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. This meant that I could then add the method

```
@Override
public void handle(final ActionEvent event)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

This then meant that I could call `button.setOnAction(this);` to execute the action

Comment: Consider instead `button.setOnAction(this::handle);`, and *not* implementing the `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` interface (also remove the `@Override` annotation). The reason this is preferable is that if you needed to do the same for other listeners you now could: with your original solution you cannot implement both `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` and (for example) `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`. You can also rename the method to anything you like with this approach.